# Sign a text file with java and getting the keys and sign?

Tags: java, sign

I have a text file, which contains the version number of the app. I'm not sure about the whole thing, because I met this thing yesterday, and my english is not the best. Here's a code that I've put together (well just copied the java tut):

```
public class FileValidator {

    public static void signFile(File file, File pkey, File sign) {
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DSA", "SUN");
            SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");
            keyGen.initialize(1024, random);
            KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
            PrivateKey priv = pair.getPrivate();
            PublicKey pub = pair.getPublic();
            Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withDSA", "SUN");
            dsa.initSign(priv);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bufin = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = bufin.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                dsa.update(buffer, 0, len);
            }

            bufin.close();
            byte[] realSig = dsa.sign();

            // Save signature
            FileOutputStream sigfos = new FileOutputStream(sign);
            sigfos.write(realSig);
            sigfos.close();

            // Save public key
            byte[] key = pub.getEncoded();
            FileOutputStream keyfos = new FileOutputStream(pkey);
            keyfos.write(key);
            keyfos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static boolean fileIsValid(File file, File pkey, File sign) {
        boolean verifies = false;
        try {
            FileInputStream keyfis = new FileInputStream(pkey);
            byte[] encKey = new byte[keyfis.available()];
            keyfis.read(encKey);

            keyfis.close();

            X509EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encKey);
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("DSA", "SUN");
            PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);

            FileInputStream sigfis = new FileInputStream(sign);
            byte[] sigToVerify = new byte[sigfis.available()];
            sigfis.read(sigToVerify);
            sigfis.close();

            Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withDSA", "SUN");
            sig.initVerify(pubKey);

            FileInputStream datafis = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bufin = new BufferedInputStream(datafis);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while (bufin.available() != 0) {
                len = bufin.read(buffer);
                sig.update(buffer, 0, len);
            }

            bufin.close();

            verifies = sig.verify(sigToVerify);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return verifies;
    }
}
```

I've tried it, and it works, if I modify the file, the fileIsValid() method returns false. But the sign and pkey files are local (means easy modification). How should I store them? On a web server? Should I store both of them there or just the sign?
(Or maybe I just misunderstand the whole thing?)

Answer (score 0):

To successfully check the validity of the signature all three pieces (file, public key, signature) must fit together. If you are allowed to change all three, you can of course come up with other triples that pass the test.

If you cannot change the public key and you do not have the private key it is practically impossible to generate another file-signature combination that passes.

It depends on the use case what to store where. If you want to make sure that a downloaded file has not been tampered with you would typically get the public key from a trusted source in a trusted way and then check the validity of the signature. If that passes you can be pretty sure that the owner of the private key has signed the file and that it was not changed afterwards.

Comment: Please help me out more, I got all comfused. A little explanation what I'm trying to achieve: I want to store the local version file in a separate text file, and at the update I compare it with an online version number. The problem is, thet all 3 files are local and can be easily modified.

Comment: I don't see how a digital signature comes into play in this application.

Comment: Because the actual app and the updater are separated. So the version number needs to be in a file.